# Isomorphism for Infinite Graphs.

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that $G$ and $H$ are infinite graphs and that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $H$ and $H$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $G$. Must $G$ and $H$ be isomorphic?

I've only just started on graph theory and this is one of the bonus questions on the assignment sheet. I don't see anything in my notes regarding infinite graphs and so I don't think this can quite classify as homework.

My intuition tells me that this might be a good definition for isomorphism for infinite graphs and hence Yes to the question but I don't quite seem to have any ideas on how to prove it.

Any insight or literature on this (because I can't seem to find much on this even on the internet!) will certainly be helpful.

Comment: What is the definition of a subgraph here? Does it have to be full (i.e. do you consider a maximal spanning tree of a connected graph its subgraph)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this example works: Vertices are non-negative integers and you put edges only between two consecutive integers (this is basically the positive x-axis with the integers as vertices). This is your $G$.

Erase one edge in $G$. This is $H$.

Show that this is a counterexample...

Comment: Works as long as the subgraphs don't have to be induced.

Comment: @Nick: Not really. Consider the subgraph induced on $\{0,2,3,\ldots\}$. (By "not really", I mean that induced or not, it doesn't really matter, it works either way.)

Comment: @Nick: I meant as a subgraph of $G$... It's clearly isomorphic to $H$.

Comment: @Nick: To make it clear $V_G=\{0,1,2,3,...\}, E_G=\{01,12,23,..\}$ and $V_H=\{0,1,2,3,...\}, E_H=\{12,23,..\}$... Then $G$ is isomorphic to the subgraph of $H$ induced by $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ while $H$ is isomorphic to the subgraph of $G$ induced by $\{0,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: ah, I see. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Nick no problem, I would had probably not seen it either without tomasz help :)

Comment: Sorry but I don't so how that is a counterexample? It seems like $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic from this construction.

Comment: @HaikalYeo $G$ is connected but $H$ is not....

Comment: Oh dear. How did I not see that?! Thanks!